# Why Android Calendar.set method is giving wrong result on first modification attempt?

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am creating my own implementation of calendar UI on Android. One of its function is changing the currently viewed month calendar by simply increasing or decreasing Calendar's month value by 1.

Default calendar value was initialized using:

```
this.currentCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

Below is the onClick listener implementation to change `currentCalendar` month value.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int month = this.currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year = this.currentCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM yyyy", Locale.US);     
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case R.id.calendarNextMonthButton: // Next Button Clicked
            month++;
            break;
        case R.id.calendarPrevMonthButton: // Prev Button Clicked
            month--;
            break;
    }
    this.currentCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    Log.d("month", String.valueOf(this.currentCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
    this.monthYearText = (TextView) this.v.findViewById(R.id.calendarMonthYearText);
    this.monthYearText.setText(sdf.format(this.currentCalendar.getTime()));
}
```

After initialization completed, the Calendar is showing `currentCalendar` month and year values correctly, e.g. month = 0 (January), year = 2014.
When first I clicked the Next button, `month` value is increased by 1. `currentCalendar` month value is set using:

```
this.currentCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month); // debugger says month is 1
```

but, when I am trying to display month value of `currentCalendar`, debugger says that the month value is 2 (March) and not 1 (February). This is only happened during the first attempt of clicking the Next button. The next time I clicked the Next and Prev button, the calendar month is changing perfectly.

Is there anything wrong with the code?

PS: I am using java.util.Calendar for `currentCalendar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the *day*? I'm assuming it's today (the 29th) as you're asking right now and using `getInstance()` to get the `Calendar` ... which means that's correct; it's rolling over to March when you add one month because Feb only has 28 days.

From the [Javadoc for Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

> Calendar has two modes for interpreting the calendar fields, lenient and non-lenient. When a Calendar is in lenient mode, it accepts a wider range of calendar field values than it produces. When a Calendar recomputes calendar field values for return by get(), all of the calendar fields are normalized. For example, a lenient GregorianCalendar interprets MONTH == JANUARY, DAY_OF_MONTH == 32 as February 1.

Once that happens ... everything works perfectly as you say, because the DAY_OF_MONTH is now 1 having been normalized from Feb. 29th to Mar. 1

Comment: Yes the day is today 29th January 2014. Wow, I didn't event think of that. I set the `currentCalendar` day-of-month value to 1 before changing the month. Now it is working perfectly. Thank you for saving me hours in this.

Comment: @Aryo Glad I could help. You can also use `.add()` and `.roll()` for finer grained control - look at the last paragraph in the main description in the Javadoc.